# @angular/platform-browser is returning null

Tags: angular

I am getting an error Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined. The error is occurring in angular2-platform-node\get-dom.js file. The file contains the following code:

> var platform_browser_1 = require('@angular/platform-browser');
>   var getDOM = platform_browser_1.**platform_browser_private**.getDOM;
>   exports.getDOM = getDOM;

I am thinking this is platform_browser_1.**platform_browser_private** is resolving to undefined. This is happening after I upgraded from angular 2.0.0 to angular 4.0.1. How can I resolve this?

Comment: have a glance at this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14733

Comment: I already checked it. The suggested solution is not working for me.